# How do I properly use checkboxes for running total in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, cumulative-sum

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to programming in VB.net (started last week). I have an assignment in class that requires me to do a running total using 3 checkboxes.

I've figured out a little bit of it. My main problem right now is that when I uncheck boxes, the calculation gets weird. So far here is my code:

```
Public Class frm1
    Dim HandbagAcc As Double = 0

    Private Sub chkBoxExtra_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkBoxExtra.CheckedChanged
        '$9.99
        If chkBoxExtra.Checked = True Then
            HandbagAcc = HandbagAcc + 9.99
            txtBoxAcc.Text = FormatCurrency(HandbagAcc)
        End If
        If chkBoxExtra.Checked = False Then
            HandbagAcc = HandbagAcc - 9.99
            txtBoxAcc.Text = FormatCurrency(HandbagAcc)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub chkBoxMatching_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkBoxMatching.CheckedChanged
        '$7.99
        If chkBoxExtra.Checked = True Then
            HandbagAcc = HandbagAcc + 7.99
            txtBoxAcc.Text = FormatCurrency(HandbagAcc)
        End If

        If chkBoxExtra.Checked = False Then
            HandbagAcc = HandbagAcc - 7.99
            txtBoxAcc.Text = FormatCurrency(HandbagAcc)
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub chkBoxFour_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkBoxFour.CheckedChanged
        '$3.95
        If chkBoxExtra.Checked = True Then
            HandbagAcc = HandbagAcc + 3.95
            txtBoxAcc.Text = FormatCurrency(HandbagAcc)
        End If

        If chkBoxExtra.Checked = False Then
            HandbagAcc = (HandbagAcc - 3.95)
            txtBoxAcc.Text = FormatCurrency(HandbagAcc)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

When I check the three checkboxes the first time, the values add up nicely--but, when I uncheck a box or two, my numbers go wonky and the calculation doesn't add up. What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You handle the different checkbox events, but inside those handlers you always check the chkBoxExtra

Comment: LOL. Well... this is embarrassing. Thank you so much, Pro Grammer. I'm so blind. I should correct that and head to sleep.

Answer (score 2):

So as commented, you were checking the wrong checkbox in two of the handlers.

I'd like to offer some improvement on the code anyway. If you add your prices to the checkboxes as a tag, you can dramatically reduce the amount of code needed.

```
Dim HandbagAcc As Double = 0

Private Sub AnyCheckBox_CheckChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkBoxExtra.CheckedChanged, chkBoxMatching.CheckedChanged, chkBoxFour.CheckedChanged
    Dim currentChk As CheckBox = sender
    Dim price As Double = currentChk.Tag
    HandbagAcc = HandbagAcc + If(currentChk.Checked, price, -price)
    txtBoxAcc.Text = FormatCurrency(HandbagAcc)
End Sub
```

So, having added the tags, you don't need a separate handler for each one, and can run it all through the same handler:
`Handles chkBoxExtra.CheckedChanged, chkBoxMatching.CheckedChanged, chkBoxFour.CheckedChanged`

The specific checkbox is grabbed through the `sender` parameter and cast to `CheckBox` so you can access specific properties of that type.

Grab the tag and cast to `Double` so you have the value to add/subtract from your total.

Now this line:

`HandbagAcc = HandbagAcc + If(currentChk.Checked, price, -price)`

The inline `If` allows you to compact the following:

```
If currentChk.Checked Then
    HandbagAcc += price
Else
    HandbagAcc -= price
End If
```

`+=` being the short way of doing `x = x + y`

Answer (score 0):

SImpler method, make use of a more flexible property

**REMOVE**

```
Dim HandbagAcc As Double = 0
```

**REPLACE WITH**

```
Public ReadOnly Property HandbagAcc() as Double
    Get
        Dim Sum As Double
        If chkBoxExtra.Checked Then Sum += 9.99
        If chkBoxMatching.checked Then Sum += 7.99
        If chkBoxFour.Checked Then Sum +=  3.95
        Return Sum
    End Get
End Sub
```

**CREATE COMMON HANDLER**

```
Private Sub AnyCheckBox_CheckChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
       Handles _
       chkBoxExtra.CheckedChanged, _
       chkBoxMatching.CheckedChanged, _ 
       chkBoxFour.CheckedChanged

    txtBoxAcc.Text = FormatCurrency(HandbagAcc)

End Sub
```